# How smart sort in QTablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt

thanks and I´m speak spanish, please be pasient:

I need make a smart sort on may QTableWidget and I don’t have any idea on how to do this, my data in the table is this:

Example:

```
Item1: “12 GB”
Item1: “34 KB”
Item1: “45 MB”
Item1: “12 bytes”
Item1: “12 MB”
Item1: “12.3 KB”
Item1: “23.4 KB”
```

Comment: The data in the column are the contemn of a foldier, and hay need make a smart sort, when the user click de hader of the column the  data need to be sorted by size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying to change your input so you actually get the amount in bytes instead of human readable values.

After that you can still display it in a different way. If that's not an option than you can try something like this to decode it:

```
def convert(value):                                                                                                                                                               
    number, multiplier = value.split()                                                                                                                                            
    if multiplier == 'bytes':                                                                                                                                                     
        multiplier = 1                                                                                                                                                            
    elif multiplier == 'KB':                                                                                                                                                      
        multiplier = 2**10                                                                                                                                                        
    elif multiplier == 'MB':                                                                                                                                                      
        multiplier = 2**20                                                                                                                                                        
    elif multiplier == 'GB':                                                                                                                                                      
        multiplier = 2**30                                                                                                                                                        
    else:                                                                                                                                                                         
        raise RuntimeError('Unknown unit %r in %r' % (multiplier, value))                                                                                                         

    return float(number) * multiplier
```

Comment: Man I don’t understand you, I need that the data y the column get automatically sort when the user click in the header of the column

Comment: @Nightmare: if that's the problem than there is a simple solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304199/how-to-sort-a-qtablewidget-with-my-own-code

Comment: ok, man thanks. the __lt__ is a internal function of the QTableWidgetItem, how can i see all these functions?

Comment: They are all in the docs, but not always obvious to find: http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__lt__