# Sort by column but with custom sorting algorithm?

Tags: python, pyside2

I found a solution for PyQt4 here:
[How to sort a QTableWidget with my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304199/how-to-sort-a-qtablewidget-with-my-own-code)
(my code and what i need to do is almost the same as in link, instead i use TableView and PySide2)

I have to use Pyside2 in this project.

Instead `self.tableView.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)` how would I use something like `self.tableView.sortByColumn(0, MyCustomSorting)` when the user clicks on a header of a column.

Thank you

Comment: If you're using QTableView then you're using your own model, so you cannot use what's proposed in that link, and sorting must be done from the model. Consider using [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) and implement `lessThan`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. but i am to noob i guess.. I couldn't figure this out by myself.. I don't know how to implement the lessThan and i don't know how to connect it so that when the user clicks the arrow of the header in the table to sort (like Ascending or Descending - except i need my own ascending and descending custom sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hint of @musicamante provided in the comments i manged to figure this out I think.
First I reimplement the `lessThan` method from `QSortFilterProxyModel` as `My_QSortFilterProxyModel`

```
class My_QSortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)

        try:  # For table Nuke scripts)
            if leftData > rightData:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

This compares the previous and after value (left and right) as i understand it, and if it returns True, the leftData is displayed first, if False the rightData is displayed first.

And later in my main class, normally we assign `self.my_proxy_model = My_QSortFilterProxyModel()` instead.